# Multithreaded .NET HTTPClient concurrent requests slow performance

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, dotnet-httpclient

I have a service that runs a number of simple sockets that receive Protobuf messages, typically comprised of requests to send to a single remote REST service location.  Each thread has it's own HttpClient instance that it uses. 
 When running a single thread at a very high rate, the performance seems to behave as expected, with very fast response rates.  If I allow multiple concurrent requests, ie. a request to send on two different threads, performance dips considerably.  Adding more threads acts similarly.

I have set the default connection limit and set the threadpool minimum threads:

```
             ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;

            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20);
```

I set up a .NET Core simple REST service that accepts the requests and just returns a simple 200 response so I could eliminate the external service as being part of the issue, and I see exactly the same results - increased time as more threads are used at a certain threshold (sub 200ms).

In the .NET Core Rest logging output, I see increased Executed Action times, from very quick (<10ms) to 50+, 100+ms as the requests come in at high rates (ie. without a sleep of about 200ms per thread after receiving the request).

I am unclear on what is going on here.  Is there a way to improve concurrent HttpClient request performance?

Some of the code:

```
    public void OpenPorts(int port, IServiceCommunication)
    {
        if (Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            Logger.Debug("Opening port " + port);

         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SocketThreadPort("tcp://*:" + port, serviceToUse); });
    }
}

private async void SocketThreadPort(string port, IServiceCommunication externalService)
    {
        int threadId = (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
        int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadId = " + threadId);
        Console.WriteLine("ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId);
        while (true)
        {
            if (Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
                Logger.Debug("Sending on " + port);
            var reply = await externalService.Send(sendingData).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
}
```

IServiceCommunication is just a wrapper around HttpClient for all intents and purposes.  Here's the send:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }
```

Is there any way to improve performance?  Is this expected?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't see how issuing **asynchronous** requests from more than one thread would increase the # of requests. Why not just issue them from a single loop, *n-at-a-time*?

Comment: @spender The internal server will receive messages in a very large quantity.  It has four to eight ports that correspond with four to eight threads in this service.  It can send up to eight simultaneous messages to be sent on to the remote server which can accept (apparently) many, many simultaneous requests on separate connections.
Shouldn't 8 parallel threads sending as fast as possible on 8 separate TCP connections be faster than a single TCP connection queue?